# I am not able to enter data into my database using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert data into a MySQL table using PHP, but when I press send in the PHP form, get this error:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

1) My php form:

```html
<form method="post" action="process_addstud.php">
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">

<th colspan="2" align="left">Add Student</h2>

  <tr>
    <td width="100">First Name</td>
    <td>
      <input name="trigger1" type="text" id="trigger1">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="100">Last Name</td>
    <td>
      <input name="reply2" type="text" id="reply2">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <td width="100"> </td>
  <td>
    <input name="save" type="submit" id="save" value="Add Student">
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

2) The send PHP:

```
<?php

//set up for mysql Connection
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'DB_user';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
//test if the connection is established successfully then it will proceed in next process else it will throw an error message
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//we specify here the Database name we are using
mysql_select_db('DB_name');
$trigger1 = $_POST['trigger1'];
$reply2 = $_POST['reply2'];

//It wiil insert a row to our tblstudent`
$sql = "INSERT INTO `DB_name`.`replies` (`trigger`, `reply`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '{$trigger1}', '{$reply2}');";
//we are using mysql_query function. it returns a resource on true else False on error
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("New Record is Added to the Database");
                        window.location = "addStudent.php";
                    </script>
                    <?php
//close of connection
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

3) Mysql code: Here I have the "usercontrib" and "rid" but i don't want to change those two columns.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `replies` (
  `trigger` text NOT NULL,
  `reply` text NOT NULL,
  `usercontrib` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=316 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Just remove NULL from your query :

`$sql = "INSERT INTO `DB_name`.`replies` (`trigger`, `reply`) 
  VALUES ('{$trigger1}', '{$reply2}');";`

Comment: It's also **strongly** advised to use `mysqli` over `mysql` for security reasons amongst others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your INSERT statement, you've got three values in the list of values, but only two columns to accept those values:

```
INSERT INTO DB_name.replies (`trigger`, `reply`) 
    VALUES (NULL, 'two', 'three')
```

Either specify three columns in the column list, or remove one of the values from the values list.

---

Some other notes:

Your code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Potentially unsafe values included in SQL text **must** be properly escaped. Better yet, use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.

Don't use deprecated **mysql_** interface; use **mysqli_** or **PDO** instead.